# Acessing columns using dropdownlist items

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database

I have two dropdownlists displaying currency:

```
1:Euro                     1:Euro                
2:Dollar                   2:Dollar
3:Pound                    3:Pound
```

And a table

```
CurrencyID  CurrencyName Rupee                  Euro                   Dollar                 Pound
----------- ------------ ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ----------------------
1           Rupee        1                      0.008                  0.009                  0.007
2           Euro         121.3                  1                      1.08                   0.84
3           Dollar       111.4                  0.91                   1                      0.77
4           Pound        143.6                  1.18                   1.28                   1
```

Is it possible to insert data using an insert statment and ddl.Text?

Something like, `INSERT INTO table WHERE ddl.SelectedItem.Text = Currencyname and ddl2.SelectedItem = (other row)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I figures it out. Its been  along day

```
UPDATE CurrencyTbl
SET Euro = '1'
WHERE CurrencyName='Euro';
```

Comment: thought you were after of an insert?

Comment: So did I but I realise UPDATE does what i need :)